# Angular Modules not recognizing imported modules

Tags: angular, module

I am trying to import a module into a home-page module, but it is throwing a TypeScript error stating that it cannot find the module despite the fact that it is defined. This is the terminal error -

ERROR in src/app/home-page/home-page.module.ts(11,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'UtilityComponentModule'.

My UtilityComponentModule is set up-

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ModalWindowComponent } from './modal-window/modal-window.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ModalWindowComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ModalWindowComponent
  ]
})
export class UtilityComponentModule { }
```

And the module I'm attempting to import it into is set up as -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomePageControllerComponent } from './home-page-controller/home-page-controller.component';
import { LanguageBarComponent } from './language-bar/language-bar.component';
import { SnippetAdderComponent } from './snippet-adder/snippet-adder.component';
import { SnippetCardComponent } from './snippet-card/snippet-card.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UtilityComponentModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomePageControllerComponent,
    LanguageBarComponent,
    SnippetAdderComponent,
    SnippetCardComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HomePageControllerComponent
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

Completely blindsided as to what could be causing this error.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or direction you have.

Cheers!

Comment: Where exactly did you `import` it in your `HomePageModule` ? You might want to add something like `import { UtilityComponentModule } from 'path-to-the-module'`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do, but I was trying with just the ./path and had to actually go as far as src/app/path. Thank you for taking the time to answer this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the `import` list, in the top of your second file as

```
import { UtilityComponentModule } from 'your path';
```

Comment: After adding the module to the second file I received another error-
ERROR in ./src/app/home-page/home-page.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './utility-component/utility-component.module' in '/Users/jbyron/Desktop/code-snip/src/app/home-page'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
ERROR in src/app/home-page/home-page.module.ts(3,40): error TS2307: Cannot find module './utility-component/utility-component.module'.

Comment: I figured it out. This just seems so obvious and I had tried your recommendation and was getting the error I posted above. I wasn't able to use the ./path and I had to actually type out the src/app/path. I have it up and working. Thank you for taking the time to answer this question!

Comment: Using `./foo` means that you are refering foo that is in your current folder. If you need to go back a folder you need `../`. Don't know if that is the case :)